# self hosted open source document management apps?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql, web-applications, recommendations

I'm looking an open source self hosted  PHP and MySQL document management apps.

- security: accessing a document by specific users
- Work flow: by admin approval (may be two admins)
- document supporting:  .pdf  and common Microsoft office file formats
- view documents online instead of downloading like pdf and doc files (downloads allows by admin

I was looking [knowledge tree futures](http://www.knowledgetree.com/features)  if there is an open source alternative for knowledge tree i will prefer that.

any suggestion?

Comment: Any other criteria? Configurable security? Workflows? Searching/indexing across particular document types?

Comment: By workflows I mean, can you set people up, for examp,e so that they can't publish documents, but can send to someone else for approval who can then publish them. Or you might need two people to approve them. That link is useful though, as people can try and look for those features in OpenSource apps.

Comment: @paulmorriss Yes you are right! that is what i'm saying.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

KnowledgeTree has a [community edition](http://www.knowledgetree.org/Main_Page) which is free and Open Source. It's a fine product and has many unique features that you won't find in any other OpenSource document management solutions (like the WIndows drag & drop client), but usage often feels kludgy, and its architecture is largely based on deprecated PHP4  code. I set it up for a client earlier this year, but we agreed to turn away from it because we discovered ...

**My recommendation**

[**ResourceSpace**](http://resourcespace.org/). It is clearly built mainly for the archival of visual media, but it has so far been working fine for documents as well (with some limitations, see below). It is completely Open Source, based on PHP, and very quick to install. It has extensive workflow features, a very nice-looking interface, and on-line preview of many document types.

**Caveats**

The only thing it doesn't seem to be doing is full-text index Word documents - I have a [Google Groups question](http://groups.google.com/group/resourcespace/browse_thread/thread/d578762924939841) running on the topic. It uses [OpenOffice integration](http://wiki.resourcespace.org/index.php/OpenOffice_Integration) to create previews of Office documents which which I'm currently having character set issues (Umlauts breaking in the document preview). I don't know whether these can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to your comment

> so may i get advice? i thought you will give me after you know my criteria :)

I was just making the question clear so that other people could help you! The only open source document management system I'm familiar with is Plone. It is powerful, and so probably fairly complicated to set up.